# Multi-threading C# 2.0 confusion

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to figure out how to multi-thread an application. I am stuck trying to find the entry point to start the thread.

The thread that I am trying to start is :  plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs);

```
...
PluginBase plugin = Plugins.GetPlugin(Commands.GetInternalName(command));
plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs);
...
```

The FireOnCommand method is:

```
 public void FireOnCommand(BotShell bot, CommandArgs args)
```

I am not having any luck using ParameterizedThreadStart or ThreadStart, I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

EDIT: Tried both

```
Thread newThread = 
  new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs)));
```

and

```
Thread newThread = 
  new Thread(new ThreadStart(plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs)));
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs)));
and  Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(plugin.FireOnCommand(this, newArgs)));

Comment: Use "edit" on your post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code:

```
class BotArgs
{
    public BotShell Bot;
    public CommandArgs Args;
}

public void FireOnCommand(BotShell bot, CommandArgs args)
{
    var botArgs = new BotArgs {
        Bot = bot,
        Args = args
    };
    var thread = new Thread (handleCommand);
    thread.Start (botArgs);
}

void handleCommand (BotArgs botArgs)
{
    var botShell = botArgs.Bot;
    var commandArgs = botArgs.Args;
    //Here goes all the work
}
```

Comment: @Kamil the method signature needs to be void foo() or void foo(object) - for ThreadStart or ParameterizedThreadStart

Comment: Woot thanks, Had to make some modifications on it to compile, but got it to work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

In .NET 2, you would need to create a method for this, with a custom type.  For example, you could do:

```
internal class StartPlugin
{
    private BotShell bot;
    private CommandArgs args;
    private PluginBase plugin;

    public StartPlugin(PluginBase plugin, BotShell bot, CommandArgs args)
    {
       this.plugin = plugin;
       this.bot = bot;
       this.args = args;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        plugin.FireOnCommand(bot, args);
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
StartPlugin starter = new StartPlugin(plugin, this, newArgs);

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(starter.Start));
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Easy to forget how much simpler life is with captured variables. Iterator blocks even more so.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus You need some object to hold your values, though.  There's no built in Tuple in .NET 2, so it's difficult without writing something for this custom.

Answer (score 2):

You should not really create your own Thread object unless you are planning on interacting with it, specifically with the thread it represents. And with interacting, I mean stopping it, starting it again, aborting it, pausing it or anything like that. If you have just an operation that you want asynchronized, you should go for the ThreadPool instead. Try this:

```
private class FireOnCommandContext
{
    private string command;
    private BotShell bot;
    private CommandArgs args;

    public FireOnCommandContext(string command, BotShell bot, CommandArgs args)
    {
        this.command = command;
        this.bot = bot;
        this.args = args;
    }

    public string Command { get { return command; } }
    public BotShell Bot { get { return bot; } }
    public CommandArgs Args { get { return args; } }
}

private void FireOnCommandProc(object context)
{
    FireOnCommandContext fireOnCommandContext = (FireOnCommandContext)context;
    PluginBase plugin = Plugins.GetPlugin(Commands.GetInternalName(fireOnCommandContext.Command));
    plugin.FireOnCommand(fireOnCommandContext.Bot, fireOnCommandContext.Args);
}

...
FireOnCommandContext context = new FireOnCommandContext(command, this, newArgs);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FireOnCommandProc, context);
```

Note that this will do the work in a separate thread, but it will NOT notify you once its done, or anything.

Please also note that I was *guessing* your `command` to be of string type. If it isn't, just set the type to the correct one.